# Move image with touchmove event on iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, ipad

I have a website that has a fixed background image which I am trying to adapt for the iPhone and iPad as the image does not stay static. I have tried various wrappers with no luck; either I can't scroll one way, or the site doesn't scroll properly (because of the use of dynamic ajax). So I started looking if there was a way to move the image background with the scrolling of the page and I used the following:

```
$(document).bind('touchmove',function(e){
    $('.background_image').css({top: $(document).scrollTop()});
$('.background_image img').css({top: $(document).scrollTop()});
console.log($('.background_image img').css('top'));
});

$(document).bind('scroll', function() {
    $('.background_image').css({top: $(document).scrollTop()});
    $('.background_image img').css({top: $(document).scrollTop()});
});
```

This seems to work for the first 'touch', but the background does not then continually move. When I stop moving the 'scroll' bind kicks in and moves the image in to the correct place. 
Is this a possible feat or am I trying to achieve the impossible here? Logging the output shows that the css is indeed being changed, but the screen is not being updated with it.

UPDATE

I don't know if it helps, but here is the HTML/CSS I'm using currently:

```
<div class="background_image">
    <img src="image.jpg" />
</div>

.background_image {
position: fixed;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: -1;
}

.background_image img {
position: fixed;
overflow: hidden;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
background: white;  
}
```

Have also changed my code to something slightly easier.

Cheers,

Dan

Comment: have you tried making the image an actual background image and just updating the src of that image? (i.e. using `background-image:url('image.jpg');
background-position:top center;
background-repeat:no-repeat;` )? Remember, `position:fixed` does not work on iOS devices (because they scroll the viewport, not the document).

Comment: @ampersand - I have tried using just the background-image tag, but the image just stays in the same location when scrolling, and not in keeping within the viewport which is ideally what I need. Also I am cross-fading the backgrounds with each page change, so its not the ideal solution (although if it worked I'd be happy to leave it at that)

Comment: can you post a link to a sample that that demonstrates some of your issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This seems to work for the first 'touch', but the background does not then continually move. When I stop moving the 'scroll' bind kicks in and moves the image in to the correct place. Is this a possible feat or am I trying to achieve the impossible here? Logging the output shows that the css is indeed being changed, but the screen is not being updated with it.

Unfortunately, this is impossible at the moment on iOS devices. I've been using jQuery Mobile for a while for iOS-optimized sites, and this is one of the big drawbacks. The jQuery Mobile team describes the problem like this (see **[here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/api/events.html)**.):

> Note that iOS devices freeze DOM manipulation during scroll, queuing them to apply when the scroll finishes.

That's the reason for the behavior you are observing. The events are being queued and updating the bg image after the scroll finishes. You most likely would be able to fix this issue by using **[iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4)**, which completely replaces the native scroll handler in a container of your choosing, though I am not sure if it is worth it for the task you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yeah I thought that may have been the case...I have tried using iScroll, YUI Scroll and some others, however the functionality of the site seems to suffer badly when I try to wrap the site (excluding the background image div section) in them.

Comment: that's just as I expected. Those tools are pretty cool but not entirely without their own problems. I'm afraid the answer is that you won't be able to do this, for the reason I posted above.

Answer (score 0):

We have decided to go with a workaround solution, and implement pictures for the iPhone that fade out at the bottom to a designated background color.